# Naming getters and properties in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a custom widget written with PyQt4:

```
class WRecordIdWidget(QtGui.QLineEdit):

    ....

    def model(self):
        return self._model
    def setModel(self, model):
        self._model = model
    model = QtCore.pyqtProperty(str, model, setModel)
```

I made a pyqt property called `model` - to be able to edit it in Qt Designer.

I named the getter `model()` according to Qt coding standards. But property is also called `model`, shadowing the getter.

So Qt Designer will see the `model` property, but i will not be able to call the getter in Qt anymore - widget.model() will raise an error. I don't know how C++ handles this and how in C++ getters and Qt properties have the same names.

Should i just rename the getter to `getModel()`? Then it will not be in line with other 'built-in' getters...

Answer (score 1):

Just rename it. When doing `model = QtCore.pyqtProperty(str, model, setModel)` you're effectively replacing the getter with the property in the class' dictionary, so you just lose direct access to it.